# SQL Server : query two columns from table1 in one row on result

Tags: sql-server, join

I have the following tables:

```
Manufacturer:                      Model range:

IDManufacturer   Manufacturer      IDModelRange  IDManufacturer ModelRange

1                Mercedes          1             1              Benz
2                Audi              2             1              E-Klasse
                                   3             2              TT
                                   4             2              A4
```

I would like to query the data from both tables and the result to be like:

```
IDManufacturer+ModelRange
1              Benz
1              E-Klasse
```

I tried all joins but I couldn't find the right one. Need some help! Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a join at all?   Both columns in your output are in the ModelRange table.

Comment: @TabAlleman - I need them in a join, because I want to use the data to Bind a Combo in a project.

Comment: even with a combo if the combo as the Name (example: Mercedes) as the Text and the ID as the Value, you can query on a single select without joins

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to find the Models for a specific Manufacturer.

If you are filtering by the ID you don't need the JOIN as stated in the comments.

If you are filtering by the name you can do it with a INNER JOIN. Here is an example:

```
Declare
    @myManufacturerChoice VARCHAR(100) = 'Mercedes';

SELECT
    M.IDManufacturer,
    mo.ModelRange Manufacturer
from Manufacturer M
inner join [Model range] mo on
    M.IDManufacturer = mo.IDManufacturer
where
    M.Manufacturer = @myManufacturerChoice
```

Also a reference [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) about joins.